# Passing variable to python from JS not working in Bokeh

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kernel, bokeh

This issue is breaking my mind
I cannot pass simple variable to python from JS in Bokeh.
So, something like this is working fine:

```
from IPython.display import HTML

input_form = """
<div style="background-color:gainsboro; border:solid black; width:300px; padding:20px;">
Variable Name: <input type="text" id="var_name" value="foo"><br>
Variable Value: <input type="text" id="var_value" value="bar"><br>
<button onclick="set_value()">Set Value</button>
</div>
"""

javascript = """
<script type="text/Javascript">
    function set_value(){
        var var_name = document.getElementById('var_name').value;
        var var_value = document.getElementById('var_value').value;
        var command = var_name + " = '" + var_value + "'";
        console.log("Executing Command: " + command);
        
        var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
        kernel.execute(command);
    }
</script>
"""

HTML(input_form + javascript)
```

While this code from Bokeh is not working!!!
Python keeps returning "name 'inds' is not defined"

```
source.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(p=p), code="""


var inds = cb_obj.get('selected')['1d'].indices;
    var d1 = cb_obj.get('data');
    console.log(d1)
    var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel;
    IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("inds = " + inds); """)
```

Any help?

Comment: Please (always) provide relevant version information. Unless your version of Bokeh is *years* old, then that is not the way to access selection indicis. Are there errors in the browser javascript console?

Comment: BokehJS 1.4.0 it is not years old. Actually Custom JS itself is working. I am using Bokeh callbacks for selection and visualisation into table - OK

Comment: the point is that when I want to save that table of selected points into any file - variables turn out to be not set

Comment: here is the working part of code:```s1.selected.js_on_change(
    "indices",
    CustomJS(
        args=dict(s1=s1, s2=s2, table=table),
        code="""
        var inds = cb_obj.indices;
        var d1 = s1.data;
        var d2 = s2.data;
        d2['x'] = []
        d2['y'] = []
        for (var i = 0; i < inds.length; i++) {
            d2['x'].push(d1['x'][inds[i]])
            d2['y'].push(d1['y'][inds[i]])
        }
        s2.change.emit();
        table.change.emit();
       
    """,
    ),
)```

Comment: What messages are in the browser JavaScript console?

Comment: In any case, the migration note about selection indices (from two and a half years ago): https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/releases.html#release-0-12-15 If you are using Bokeh 1.4 you should definitely use the new method described there.